# Test & Enable Mailbox in CRM 2013?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, server-side-sync

In CRM 2013, is "Test & Enable Mailbox" in a Mailbox only for Server Side Sync?

My Email Router setup works fine but when I run "Test & Enable Mailbox" I consistently get a Failure status, with the resulting alert stating the following:

> The email message "Test Message" cannot be sent because the mailbox ***** does not have an email server profile associated with it or the email server profile is inactive.

Aren't "email server profiles" only for Server Side Sync?

If so, does that mean I don't have to be concern about failed tests because I'm using the Email Router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, "Test & Enable Mailbox"  in the mailbox is only to test and see if the Server Side sync is functioning correctly.